# Find main memory location in cache(direct mapping)

Tags: cpu-cache

Consider main memory of the size 64 kB with each word being 8 bits(one byte) only and a direct mapping Cache memory of size 4 kB also having data word size 8 bits.

Find the following :

- 1. Find the size of tag and index fields of cache?
- 2. In what location of cache hexadecimal address to main memory (AABB) (if exists in cache) will be located?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This question appears poorly written and formatted, which is not acceptable in this community. As a result, this question is liable to downvotes unless edited.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question is 4 tag bits and cache index bits should be 4 as it is byte-addressable so address bus size is 8 bits so the physical address is therefore of 8 bits and **cache index = physical address - tag bits**.
Approach : **tag bits = lg(main-memory size/ cache-memory size)**. Also clarifying the question will help, I don't think memory is byte-addressable if at all 2nd question has to make sense since **AABB** will take 16-bit address bus. Or according to the question, it won't exist.